# How do I associate an object with a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects in javascript. Each row in my table represents about 3 properties from one object in the array. I have a jquery event handler for an `<input type="text"/>`'s blur event. I want to be able to update the object in the array. The problem is that I have no idea which row is associated with which object in the array.

**Is there any way that I can attach a reference to each of my objects to the rows?** I tried attaching it directly as shown below, but I can't access the `attachedObject` when the blur event is fired.

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
row.attachedObject = myObject;
```

Here is my blur method, where I try to set the value of the attached object's title property. Unfortunately on debugging, the attached object shows up as undefined even though it shows up in the method where it was attached to the row.

```
    $(document).on('blur', '.name-cell', function(e) {
        var value = $(event.target).val();
        var row = $(event.target).closest("tr");
        row.attachedObject.title = $(event.target).val();
        e.preventDefault();  // to prevent the default action of anchor elements
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Save object identifier as an input attribute or table row attribute:

```
<input type="text" data-target="<obj.id>" ... />
```

or

```
<tr data-target="<obj.id>">
```

This will allow you to get that value later on in blur handler function:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.name-cell', function(e) {
        var value = $(event.target).val();
        var row = $(event.target).closest("tr");
        var id = $(row).attr('data-target');
        row.attachedObject.title = $(event.target).val();
        e.preventDefault();  // to prevent the default action of anchor elements
    });
```